# Expand columns on hiding other columns

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4

I have the below HTML and CSS. If one of the columns is hidden, I want to expand the other 3 columns. I don't think I can use `col-md-3` for this scenario.

How can I do this?

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3" *ngIf="hideCol1">
    Column 1
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3" *ngIf="hideCol2">
    Column 2
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3" *ngIf="hideCol3">
    Column 3
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3" *ngIf="hideCol4">
    Column 4
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should be able to use the accordion control if you are using the twitter bootstrap library. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/

Answer (score 3):

You can use `col-md` (or just `col`) class to adjust columns automatically.

> Thanks to flexbox, grid columns without a specified width will
>   automatically layout as equal width columns. For example, four
>   instances of .col-sm will each automatically be 25% wide from the
>   small breakpoint and up. See the auto-layout columns section for more
>   examples.
>   https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#how-it-works

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#auto-layout-columns

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md" *ngIf="hideCol1">
    Column 1
  </div>
  <div class="col-md" *ngIf="hideCol2">
    Column 2
  </div>
  <div class="col-md" *ngIf="hideCol3">
    Column 3
  </div>
  <div class="col-md" *ngIf="hideCol4">
    Column 4
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you mean that when hiding a column via `*ngIf` you want the remaining columns to responsively resize themselves, you can just set each column's class to "col", instead of specifying the col size.